# Pass variable from view to form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

```
@app.route('/product/<unique_form>',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def product(unique_form):
    form = ProductForm(**product_data)
```

---

```
class ProductForm(Form):
  #form

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       #Here in the __init__ I need to access the unique_form value
       Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I know that i can use sessions for this, but probably there is a way of pass the variable from the view to the form class.

Something like this:

```
form = ProductForm(unique_form, **product_data)
```

This is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
@app.route('/product/<unique_form>',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def product(unique_form):
    form = ProductForm(unique_form, **product_data)

class ProductForm(Form):
   def __init__(self, unique_form, *args, **kwargs):
       # well, now you have unique_form here
       Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```