# WTForms and passing a var to a form class

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using wtforms from flask.

I tried this post and does not work:

[Pass variable from view to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684878/pass-variable-from-view-to-form)

I just simply wan t to pass a variable to a form an d proving to be difficult

e.g. this works

```
 class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    MY FORM CODE HERE

 form = MyForm()
```

But I want to do this:

```
lookupid = "wtforms is painful"
form = MyForm(lookupid)
```

I tried this but does not work:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):

   def __init__(self, lookupid=None):
      FlaskForm.__init__(self)
   print self.lookupid


   NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: If you `print lookupid` does it print `"wtforms is painful"`?

Comment: what about indentation in your MyForm constructor? Shouldn't `print` be a little to the right? Also it's better to use `super().__init__(self)`

Comment: it prints NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Isn't it an indentation issue, as it has been stated above?